# Is this possible to install node-sass offline proxy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, sass, node-sass

I'm trying to install node-sass module using npm but each time an error displayed about a problem in network configuration that's because i'm using proxy and private registry this is the error :

```
This is most likely not a problem with node-gyp or the package itself and is related to network connectivity In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network setting
```

[image]

Is it possible to install this module offline ?

Comment: as of today MARCH 2020 . THIS DOES NOT WORK AT ALL .

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had a similar problem, while trying to install node-sass behind a corporate proxy. 
What you can try is:

1. Download it locally from here:https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases (choose the right one depending on your OS)
2. Use the binary configuration parameter [–sass-binary-path](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters). to install it.

   `npm install --sass-binary-path="C:\src\v4.7.2\win32-x64-57_binding.node"`

Comment: The paramter name uses dashes between each word. `--sass-binary-path` See https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters

Comment: Which file(s) should be downloaded? for example there is lots of files targeting `windows x64`, e.g: `win32-x64-72_binding.node`, `win32-x64-72_binding.pdb`, `win32-x64-79_binding.node`, `win32-x64-79_binding.pdb`, ...

Comment: If I remember correctly you only need  the '.node' file. In your case, it should be `win32-x64-79_binding.node`. If you want the newest version.

Comment: CAUTION - THIS DOES NOT WORK AS OF MARCH 2020

Comment: I think this STILL WORK. Note that for older version node.js, `node module version` of `_binding.node` file is important. In case `win32-x64-72_binding.node` , node module version is 72.  For example, Node.js 10.15 for Windows requires `win32-x64-64_binding.node` or `win32-ia32-64_binding.node`.

Comment: I can confirm this binary parameter configuration command still works for node@12.X and the win32-x64-72_binding.node binary file.

Answer (score 5):

#### How-to

1. Download the binary here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases
   It vary depending on your OS and node version.
2. Set up env variable (see https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters)
   `export SASS_BINARY_PATH=<absolute_path_to_file>`

Replace `<absolute_path_to_file>` by the path to the file you have downloaded. The path should be absolute, and in linux format (if you use git bash, with cmd use Windows format). To get the absolute path, you can go to the directory, open a git bash console and do `pwd`, append the filename, and you should have something like `/c/Users/you/SOFTWARE/win32-x64-64_binding.node`.

3. Install (locally)
   `npm i node-sass --save`
4. You need to export the variable once for each opened terminal using node-sass. Meaning you should add the export line to your `npm start`. (so you gotta keep the file you downloaded somewhere safe).

For example you can do `"start:dev": "set SASS_BINARY_PATH=%cd%\\win32-x64-64_binding.node && npm start"`. In this case, the sass binary is inside my project, making it easier for new collaborators. We are using `set` instead of `export` because Jetbrain IDE use by default cmd (Windows terminal).

---

#### Miscellaneous

If you get an error message like:

```
Testing binary
Binary has a problem: Error: The module '\\?\C:\Users\myself\SOFTWARE\win32-x64-72_binding.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
```

It means it have found your binary, but you took the wrong one for your current node version. Dowload the correct version, and do theses above step again.

when using npm start if you have (used on a react-script project):

```
./src/product-card-list/product-card-list.component.module.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./src/product-card-list/product-card-list.component.module.scss)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\myself\PROJECTS\advisor_spa\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'
```

You failed step 4. Export `SASS_BINARY_PATH` again and it should work.

---

If you use Webstorm, you can make run configuration for `npm start` and add full path `SASS_BINARY_PATH=C:\Users\myself\SOFTWARE\win32-x64-64_binding.node` environment variable (for Windows).

---

If you use Visual Code on Windows, you can add a system env variable, at the same level as PATH (not inside PATH).

Comment: AS OF TODAY MARCH 2020 . THIS DOES NOT WORK

Comment: @SeanCh I have tried with (latest) node-sass@4.13.1 and Node 12, this still work.

Comment: @Amroise I tried it on Windows with Node 10.15 and node-sass module 64 v 4.13.1 . It still points to online registry for installation