# I can't npm install on cloned ngx-datatable repo

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, ngx-datatable

Hello stackoverflow community!

After years of lurking around, this is finally the time to ask a question myself and perpetuate it so others can find a solution as well. When I clone other projects and run npm install it works (although I clone from my work's gitlab), so I think this is specifically for this repo. Im using ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

After cloning the repo with **git clone https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable.git**, I typed on my terminal npm install, but I get a lot of errors on the terminal and a giant log (4k+ rows).

I tried many solutions here on stackoverflow, but none of them worked. I tried **sudo npm install**, **npm update** then **npm install** and others. I really dont know what do to... I wanted to open an issue on github but support topics are supposed to be here according their github description.

Log: https://pastebin.com/LhDtYxvJ
Terminal: https://pastebin.com/pHwp9e92
(What I think is relevant) Terminal:

````
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/web/.nvm/versions/node/v16.7.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.7.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.7.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.7.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.7.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.7.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.7.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:98083) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c: In function ‘base64_encode_block’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:48:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
npm ERR!    48 |    result = (fragment & 0x003) << 4;
npm ERR!       |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:52:2: note: here
npm ERR!    52 |  case step_B:
npm ERR!       |  ^~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:62:11: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
npm ERR!    62 |    result = (fragment & 0x00f) << 2;
npm ERR!       |    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c:66:2: note: here
npm ERR!    66 |  case step_C:
npm ERR!       |  ^~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp: In function ‘void Sass::Functions::handle_utf8_error(const Sass::ParserState&, Sass::Backtraces)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:110:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_code_point’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   110 |       catch (utf8::invalid_code_point) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:114:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::not_enough_room’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   114 |       catch (utf8::not_enough_room) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp:118:20: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class utf8::invalid_utf8’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   118 |       catch (utf8::invalid_utf8) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_encode_string(const char*)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:405:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   405 |   catch (std::exception) {
npm ERR!       |               ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp: In function ‘char* json_stringify(const JsonNode*, const char*)’:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp:424:15: warning: catching polymorphic type ‘class std::exception’ by value [-Wcatch-value=]
npm ERR!   424 |   catch (std::exception) {
npm ERR!       |               ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/v8.h:30,
npm ERR!                  from /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/node.h:63,
npm ERR!                  from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/v8-internal.h: In function ‘void v8::internal::PerformCastCheck(T*)’:
npm ERR! /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:488:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
npm ERR!   488 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:488:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
npm ERR!   488 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:488:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
npm ERR!   488 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                                  ^
npm ERR! /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:488:63: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
npm ERR!   488 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                                               ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:284:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   284 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
npm ERR!       |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE render_file(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:320:98: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*)’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*)’} to ‘uv_after_work_cb’ {aka ‘void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   320 |     int status = uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &ctx_w->request, compile_it, (uv_after_work_cb)MakeCallback);
npm ERR!       |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:56,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp: At global scope:
npm ERR! /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/node.h:806:43: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   806 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
npm ERR!       |                                           ^
npm ERR! /home/web/.node-gyp/16.7.0/include/node/node.h:840:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
npm ERR!   840 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
npm ERR!       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:358:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
npm ERR!   358 | NODE_MODULE(binding, RegisterModule);
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Erro 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.11.0-34-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/web/.nvm/versions/node/v16.7.0/bin/node" "/dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /dados/repositorio/git/ngx-datatable/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.7.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1```
````

Comment: I'm not able to reach any content on the above evernote links. Could you please share the relevant terminal output in the post description? (There is a guidline on stackoverflow, that all relevant infos / code snippets should be in the post itself, not on an external dependency, because the external links might break some time and the post will not be usefull for the comunity anymore.)

Comment: Hi, I added what I think is important from the terminal output, but there are still plenty of lines missing. I put the whole terminal and logs on pastebin, since it does not require permissions to access the site. I tried to paste here, but there is a limit of characters

Comment: `node-sass` binary can not be downloaded, and a post install script trys to build it and this build fails. Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Yes I am, but other projects install fine when I npm install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `npm install` of an Angular project is running the `node-sass` thirdparty is also installed. It has a script which tries to download the sass binary. This download is blocked by the corporate proxy, and as a fallback the script tries to build the sass binaries. That can only be in that case successful if the necessary environment is given (for example Python is installed.)

To try to download the binaries through the proxy I suggest to create an `.npmrc` file in the root of the cloned project and add following content:

```
proxy=http://<proxyurl>:<port>
https-proxy=http://<proxyurl>:<port>
```

If it does not work you could give a try with following:

```
proxy=http://<username>:<pass>@proxyhostname:<port>
https-proxy=http://<username>:<pass>@proxyhostname:<port>
```

But please do not store your authentication data in a plaintext file. So if only the second one works, I suggest to remove auth data after a successful installation.

There are also alternatives to get the sass binary, they are documented [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters).

The released binaries can be found [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and kindness! I "solved it" by coping the node_modules folder it generates during the npm install process before the folder gets deleted when the error occurs. Then after the folder is deleted, I just moved the copy of the folder where it is supposed to be and it worked... IDK why

Comment: I think it works till `node-sass` is not needed somewhere. This way that dependency is missing in the `node_modules`. But if you just want to analyze some stuff in ngx-datatable code, I think it will work fine.

Comment: Great point! Can I just install the missing node-sass using npm install node-sass? Because I'm actually modifying the ngx-datatable component to add features requested by the company I work for. I already added one of the features and no problems have popped up

Comment: Yes, the binary can be downloaded from the link that I posted above. After that you need to set the `SASS_BINARY_PATH` environmental variable in your `.npmrc` file to the downloaded binary file path. More infos (and other alternatives) about this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882943/is-this-possible-to-install-node-sass-offline-proxy